# Attache debugger for File Provider Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, fileprovider-extension

I am developing a File Provider Extension for iOS. For no obvious reason, the debugger randomly stops attaching.

I am running `Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)`.

I created a fresh Project setup:

- File -> New -> Project... -> Multiplatform -> App

and then added the extension:

- File -> New -> Target... -> iOS -> File Provider Extension

Initially it worked fine, I was debugging the extension via (both simulator and real iPhone device):

- Run -> Choose an app to run: Files

I was able to see the extension's logs in the output window and debug the code using breakpoints. At some point, the debugger stopped attaching and instead it seems the File's logs are shown in the output window rather than the extension's.

I tried to clean the build folder, switch between device and simulator, restart, manually attache the debugger to the extension's process, ... None of it seems to make a difference. However, sometimes it randomly works again without having made any changes.

Is there an explanation why this is happening and how to get a stable setup?

Comment: You understand you have to switch the console to display the extension?

Comment: it is set to `All Output`

Comment: No, I mean what target it displays.

Comment: in the debug navigator it says: `Waiting to Attach`

Comment: I guess I don't understand then